# change user-agent for good

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, user-agent

I have been able to change the user-agent by using

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

NSMutableURLRequest *req = (NSMutableURLRequest *)request;
NSString *versionString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];

NSLog(@"user agent = %@", [req valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);

if ([req valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"] != NULL) {

    [req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", versionString, [req valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    NSLog(@"user agent = %@", [req valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);

   return YES
    }
}
```

But when I go to this website on the device http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ my user-agent hasn't changed. Is there a way to change the user-agent for good?

Answer (score 1):

After playing around for a really long time, I discovered that you can [change the User Agent without rooting](http://www.technipages.com/ios-change-the-user-agent-in-safari.html). Not sure if this helps you if you are building an app.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the user-agent displayed by Safari, only the one used by your own application.

Comment: Thanks duskwuff. I am still going to change the one in my app but I the user-agent is now (null). I am not sure why this is. The code is the same. This there anything I could have accidently changed to make the user-agent (null)?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the simulator reports nil when testing at times. I'm not sure if this is intentional or on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of the user agent when doing "manual" `NSURLRequest`s but I don't think you can change them in a `UIWebView`.

Reason being, the values that are passed into the method you show above are not mutable -- you can't change them and expect that the rest of the application will "take" the modifications. Honestly, I'm surprised that casting a `NSURLRequest` to its mutable variant and then changing it didn't cause your app to crash.